# Span inheriting list styles

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I have a `span` in a `li`. According to both Firebug and Chrome inspector the span is inheriting list styles `list-style-image`, `list-style-position`, `list-style-type`. Which is not what I would expect given that a span is not a list element. Anyway, because of this (I assume) the span is not being positioned where I'd like it.

How can I stop this inheritance?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the CSS specification, list-style properties only apply to elements with `display:list-item`. See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#lists

Therefore, the inherited list-style properties do not apply to the SPAN element, unless it has `display:list-item` set.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Firebug and check which class is applying the styles to the span. Simply modify that style to fix your issue. Or put a screen grab of the Firebug inspect panel here, so we can have a look

Comment: Well the styles are correct for the parent li - I'm just confused as to why they are being applied to the child span

Comment: @Richard Does the child span have `display:list-item` set? If not, then the list-style properties **do not** apply to it.

Comment: @Sime - no the span does not. I only thought the span was being affected as it is not positioned where I think it should be, and I can't see anything else effecting it (margin, padding, positioning etc)

Comment: @Richard Unless you've specifically assigned a class or targeted it, the styles will not apply. Inspect the span and check the styles that is being applied.

Comment: @Richard, can you set up an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: @JohnP - it's ok, the styles are not in fact being applied, even though they inherit them. Slightly confusing.

Comment: @JohnP Even if the SPAN had the list-style properties set explicitly via a class, they still would not apply to it unless the SPAN is `display:list-item`.

Comment: @Richard The list-style properties are not the cause of your positioning problem. You're welcome to post the CSS code. Then we may figure out the real cause of the issue.

Comment: @Sime Vidas yup, I saw your post, +1d it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your reading the information from Chrome and Firebug wrong or you've done a mistake in your CSS.

Normally, spans doesn't inherit any style related to list element automatically.

Paste your CSS, so we can help you.

Comment: List-style properties do inherit (trickle down), so the SPAN will inherit them. However, they will not affect the SPAN unless it has `display:list-item` set.

Comment: that is pretty much what I meant with my "automatically". I checked, Firebug and Chrome don't display these styles on the span if you don't treat it like a list-item.

Comment: Yes, but the SPAN will always inherit the list-style properties. They may or may not apply to it, but it will always inherit them.

Comment: I make amend for my poor wording then ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't that is just the way CSS inheritance works,

You could negate the effects by adding this to the spans:

```
.className {
list-style-image:none;
list-style-position:inherit; 
list-style-type:none;
}
```

Not that any of these should effect how the spans appear, more likely a rogue margin/padding, try using Eric Mayers [CSSReset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)